# Sonata Admin Bundle - String Validation

Tags: string, validation, symfony, bundle, sonata-admin

I've some forms in my Sonata Admin Bundle and some fields are set as "required = true". 
Now, you can circumvent this requirement with an empty string, e.g. with space.
It works even for integer-types..

How can I build a validation, which secures from some unallowed entries ?

Thank you

Comment: It's easy and you can find it in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) please read it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a custom callback validator to verify your strings with all cases you want.

Just add in your admin class:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
{
    $errorElement
        ->assertCallback(array('validateMyEntity'))
    ;
}
```

and in your entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

/**
 * Validates my entity and throw violations
 */
public function validateMyEntity(ExecutionContext $context)
{
    $title = $this->getTitle();

    if (empty($title)) {
        $context->addViolation('Title can\'t be empty.');
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: With symfony 2.5+ and sonata 2.2+ use **ExecutionContextInterface** instead of **ExecutionContext**